# How to process UTF-8 characters for an ioslides_presentation generated with rmarkdown

Tags: r, utf-8, r-markdown

I am trying to display special characters in an ioslides_presentation generated with rmarkdown, but instead of a Δ I always get <U+0394> in my final slides.
When I execute the individual R chunk it stores Δ correctly.
How do I ensure UTF-8 characters are processed correctly using rmarkdown?

---

### title: "Untitled"
author: "K"
date: "2 11 2020"
output: ioslides_presentation

Δendo=ΔEC

```
test <- c("Δendo", "ΔEC")

test
```

[encoding fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3c0V.png)

Answer (score 2):

Worth reading: [9.2 Essentials of text data](https://bookdown.org/hneth/ds4psy/9-2-text-essentials.html) [Neth, H. (2020). ds4psy: Data Science for Psychologists]

R allows typing Unicode characters by entering `backslash` as the escape character `\u...` or `\U...` — with `...` standing for a 4-digit hexadecimal code.
We can show up Unicode characters/symbols in R Markdown documents by using the `asis_output()` function of the `knitr` package:

````
---
title: "Untitled" 
author: "K" 
date: "2 11 2020" 
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Teste

```{r teste, echo = FALSE}
test <- knitr::asis_output(c("\u0394endo", "\u0394EC"))
test
```

## Teste 1

```{r teste1, echo = FALSE}
test1 <- knitr::asis_output("\u0394endo=\u0394EC")
test1
```

## Embed into inline chunk

- We can directly embed into inline chunk the `knitr::asis_output()` function:  
- When I execute the individual R chunk it stores `r knitr::asis_output("\u0394")` correctly.  
- `r knitr::asis_output("\u0394endo=\u0394EC")`
````

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! It works for the simple vectors in my example. Do you know how to apply it to a dataframe?

Comment: You may start running (in Console) the `readr::default_locale()` function to see what is your default encoding.

Comment: Then, you may specify UTF-8 in `locale`/`fileEncoding` parameters when reading (and writing) in `readr::read_csv()` or `utils::read.csv()`.

Comment: Ex.: `Myfile<- readr::read_csv(file = "file.csv", locale = readr::locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))` or `Myfile<- utils::read.csv(file = "file.csv", header = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")`

Comment: BTW, if you are on Windows set the 'Default text encoding' option: 
Tools > Global Options... > Code > Savings > Default text encoding: > Change... > UTF-8 > Apply

Comment: Also, you may find this article interesting: [Encoding in R](https://irene.rbind.io/post/encoding-in-r/#fn2)

Comment: Yes, encoding is a real pain I think! I have already set everything to UTF-8 but still run into problems when I knit a document... :-(